# Is my solution correct? (Elementary Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The problem states:

Show that for any sets $A$ and $B$, $\mathcal{P}(A\cap B) = \mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)$ by showing that the statements $x \in\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ and $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)$ are equivalent.

Here is what I did:

$\forall x\{\exists S[x\in S \wedge (x \in A \wedge x \in B)]\}$

Isn't it equivalent for both ones? $\mathcal{P}(A)$ means $\{S \mid S \subseteq A\}$, so I just add to that the conditon that $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$, and I can do the exact same thing for the right expression, proving they're equal. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

$$x\in\wp\left(A\cap B\right)\iff x\subset A\cap B\iff$$ $$x\subset A\wedge x\subset B\iff x\in\wp\left(A\right)\wedge x\in\wp\left(B\right)\iff x\in\wp\left(A\right)\cap\wp\left(B\right)$$

This is true for every $x$ so it proves that $\wp\left(A\cap B\right)=\wp\left(A\right)\cap\wp\left(B\right)$. The second $\iff$ is the essential point of the proof.